# Redux saga dispatch multi actions in DOM events sequentially

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

Can I dispatch multiple actions sequentially ?

```
  dispath({type:'CREATE_PRODUCT', data: product});
  dispath({type:'GET_LIST_PRODUCT'}); //This action must be performed after the previous action(create product) is completed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, my solution is to use promise in combination with redux-saga
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@adobe/redux-saga-promise

Answer (score 0):

you could actually do that without another library, if you want to wait until a request finishes, you can use `take` side effect and then call another function. see this: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/NonBlockingCalls

Comment: I know this can be done inside redux-saga, however I want to dispatch actions outside of redux-saga sequentially